# Boxplot in highcharts displaying incorrect values for high, and median

Tags: javascript, highcharts, statistics

I am creating a box plot from a simple series of data:

```
    var box_plot = Highcharts.chart(container, {

        chart: {
            type: 'boxplot'
        },

        title: {
            text: chart_title
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Observations',
            data: [
                [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
            ],
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>'
            }
        }]      
    });
    return box_plot;
```

But when the box plot is generated, the high is shown as 6 and median as 4. In the data the high is 13 and median is 6.

Please inform what I am doing wrong. Screenshot of code and box plot attached.

Thank You

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can provide data to boxplot series in two ways:

1. An array of arrays with 6 or 5 values. In this case, the values correspond to x,low,q1,median,q3,high. If the first value is a string, it is applied as the name of the point, and the x value is inferred. The x value can also be omitted, in which case the inner arrays should be of length 5. Then the x value is automatically calculated, either starting at 0 and incremented by 1, or from pointStart and pointInterval given in the series options.

   ```
   data: [
     [0, 3, 0, 10, 3, 5],
     [1, 7, 8, 7, 2, 9],
     [2, 6, 9, 5, 1, 3]
   ]
   ```
2. An array of objects with named values. The following snippet shows only a few settings, see the complete options set below. If the total number of data points exceeds the series' `turboThreshold`, this option is not available.

   ```
   data: [{
     x: 1,
     low: 4,
     q1: 9,
     median: 9,
     q3: 1,
     high: 10,
     name: "Point2",
     color: "#00FF00"
   }, {
     x: 1,
     low: 5,
     q1: 7,
     median: 3,
     q3: 6,
     high: 2,
     name: "Point1",
     color: "#FF00FF"
   }]
   ```

Highcharts doesn't have any auto data calculation procedure in this case. You need to prepare the required data structure by yourself. For example:

```
const data = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
];

const processedData = data.map((dataEl, index) => ({
  x: index,
  low: Math.min(...dataEl),
  median: dataEl[(dataEl.length - 1) / 2],
  high: Math.max(...dataEl),
  ...
}));
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/eqz4851x/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.boxplot.data